# Designing classes for Hotel

Tags: java, oop, object

I am about to design a class,which has list of objects, again each object in list is an another list of objects. Is there any better way to design this kind of scenario?

Here,if I want to traverse all rooms, I need to first traverse the list of floors and then the rooms.

Eg: Hotel HAS=> List of Floors HAS=> List of Rooms

```
class Room
{
  int roomNo;
  boolean occupied;
}


class Floor
{
  int floorNo;
  ArrayList<Room> roomList = new ArrayList<Room>();
}

class Hotel
{
  ArrayList<Floor> floorList = new ArrayList<Floor>();
}
```

Comment: Think about it like this: if you were actually in the hotel about to physically do this yourself, how would you do it?

Comment: @JonK I would first check for vacancy in first floor, then second..till the last floor.

Comment: Then is it strictly necessary to traverse both lists? Could you maintain a separate list that only holds vacant rooms, irrespective of which floor they're on? That makes checking for a vacant room much more efficient (all you'd be doing effectively is `vacantRooms.isEmpty()`), but you'd have to remember to remove each room from the list as they became occupied.

Comment: @JonK Okay.I can do that. I can traverse only the vacant rooms,but as you said I need to take care of maintaining the new `vacantRooms` list. Thanks

Comment: If you went down that route, you just need to make sure that your `occupy()` and `vacate()` methods (or their equivalents) properly add and remove to and from that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Eg: Hotel HAS=> List of Floors HAS=> List of Rooms

Developers need to stop trying to mimic real-life relationships between objects. Just because you say "some kind of entity has some other kind of entity" doesn't mean they both belong to a single object cluster.

What you need to look at is the **use cases (commands)** your object model will be processing and which **invariants (rules)** have to be protected during the process.

You cannot really come up with a good object model without knowing what problem it will be solving. The same hold for more traditionnal data structures; e.g. you cannot choose what's more appropriate between an `ArrayList` or a `HashMap` without knowing the data access patterns that will be used.

For instance, if you are trying to model a room reservation process where you shouldn't accept overlapping reservations then you have to create the smallest possible cluster of data that will allow your object model to fulfill this task.

Do you need to bring in memory the entire room list as well as all their reservations to fulfill a single room reservation? Probably not, so why would you need an `Hotel` object that holds a collection of `Floor` which in turn will hold a collection of `Room`?

Chances are that you only need a `Room` aggregate that carries a list of it's own upcoming reservations.

Now, for query purposes you may still want to be able to list all the rooms of a specific floor or hotel but relationships doesn't have to be expressed through object references. If a `Room` holds onto a `floorId` and a `Floor` holds onto an `hotelId` then those queries can be fulfilled through database queries.

I understand that your question was purely academic and probably have nothing to do with a real life problem, but you need to understand that object models aren't crafted out only from real-life relationships: you need to look at **commands**.

Comment: Yes,I need to design based on the usecases. But I am having trobule understanding your comments regarding overlapping reservation and `Room` aggregate. Could you please explain

Comment: @mc20 When booking a `Room`, In order to make sure that the booking doesn't conflict with another one you need a boundary around all upcoming bookings and a specific room (an object that holds all this data). Therefore, the `Room` aggregate would hold onto a collection of upcoming bookings. When calling `room.book(...)` you can then traverse bookings to see if there's a conflict or not. If there's one you reject the booking, but if there isn't then you record the booking.

Comment: @mc20 As we can see, you do not need to load an `Hotel` class to process this use case. A concurrency protection mechanism must also be put in place to avoid breaking the rules through race conditions. Usually optimistic concurrency is more efficient than pessimistic locking. I'm not sure if that answers your question or not?